# I cant quite figure out how to get these public integers to work

Tags: java, types, constructor, driver

*PUBLIC CLASS*

```
public class MonthDays {

        private int month;
        private int year;

        public int Month(int x){
            month = x;
            return x;
        }
        public int Year(int y){
            year = y;
            return y;
        }

    public int getNumberOfDays(){

        if      (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 ||          //determines if the the month entered is a month with 31 days or not
                month == 7 || month == 8 ||month == 10 || month == 12){
            return 31;
        }
        if (year % 4 == 0 && month == 2){           //determines if the month is february on a leap year
            return 29;
        }
        if (year % 4 != 0 && month ==2){            //determines if the month is february on a non leap year

            return 28;
        }
        else{                                       //any other condition is a month with 30 days
            return 30;
        }

    }
}
```

*DRIVER CLASS*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthDaysDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;
        int y;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter month: ");
        Month month = new Month(reader.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter year: ");
        Year year = new Year(reader.nextLine());




    }

}
```

im not too sure where i went wrong, but from my understanding this should be working. but im also pretty certain its a dumb error somewhere.

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile much less work as you appear to be trying to use a Month class but none exists, and rather you have a MonthDays class. Does the MonthDaysDriver class even compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you're testing is `MonthDays`. You have methods `Month` and `Year` (which should probably be called `setMonth` and `setYear`).

```
MonthDays md = new MonthDays();
System.out.println("Enter month: ");
md.Month(reader.nextInt());
System.out.println("Enter year: ");
md.Year(reader.nextInt());
```

or, if you rename the methods,

```
MonthDays md = new MonthDays();
System.out.println("Enter month: ");
md.setMonth(reader.nextInt());
System.out.println("Enter year: ");
md.setYear(reader.nextInt());
```

or, add a constructor to `MonthDays` that takes `month` and `year`.

```
public MonthDays(int month, int year) {
   this.month = month;
   this.year = year;
}
```

and call it like

```
System.out.println("Enter month: ");
int month = reader.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter year: ");
int year = reader.nextInt();
MonthDays md = new MonthDays(month, year);
```

Finally, you can call `getNumberOfDays` once you have a `MonthDays` instance. Like

```
System.out.println(md.getNumberOfDays());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get your code working. Please read about constructors in Object-Oriented Programming.

**public class**

```
public class MonthDays {

        private int month;
        private int year;

        public MonthDays(int x, int y){
            month = x;
            year = y;
        }

        public int getNumberOfDays(){

            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 month == 7 || month == 8 ||month == 10 || month == 12){ //determines if the the month entered is a month with 31 days or not
            return 31;
            }
            if (year % 4 == 0 && month == 2){           //determines if the month is february on a leap year
            return 29;
            }
            if (year % 4 != 0 && month ==2){            //determines if the month is february on a non leap year    
            return 28;
            }
            else{                                       //any other condition is a month with 30 days
            return 30;
            }

        }
    }
```

**driver class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthDaysDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;
        int y;
        int days;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter month: ");
        x = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter year: ");
        y = reader.nextInt();
        MonthDays md = new MonthDays(x, y);
        days = md.getNumberOfDays();
        System.out.println("Number of days= " + days);




    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hai You have made some basic mistakes in your code .

1) Month is a method ,not a class.You should have needed an instance of  MonthDays  to call method Month . 
As per java coding standard you should have written that as setMonth() or setYear()
2) Method Month return an int value.You should have assigned that to int value.

3) Argument of Year method also a int value.You have specified that a String value now

```
public class MonthDays 
{
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public int setMonth(int x){
        month = x;
        return x;
    }
    public int setYear(int y){
        year = y;
        return y;
    }

public int getNumberOfDays(){

    if      (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 ||          //determines if the the month entered is a month with 31 days or not
            month == 7 || month == 8 ||month == 10 || month == 12){
        return 31;
    }
    if (year % 4 == 0 && month == 2){           //determines if the month is february on a leap year
        return 29;
    }
    if (year % 4 != 0 && month ==2){            //determines if the month is february on a non leap year

        return 28;
    }
    else{                                       //any other condition is a month with 30 days
        return 30;
    }

}
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthDaysDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;
        int y;
        MonthDays MD=new MonthDays();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter month: ");
        int month = MD.setMonth(reader.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter year: ");
        int year = MD.setYear(reader.nextInt());
        int numberOfDays=MD.getNumberOfDays();
        System.out.println("Number oF days in that month :"+numberOfDays);


    }

}
```